# How can I merge two streams with identical columns in Pentaho?

Tags: merge, stream, append, transformation, pentaho

I am new user in Pentaho and maybe my question is very simple. I have two streams with identical columns, e.g. stream S1 has the columns: `A`, `B`, `C`, and stream S2 has columns: `A`, `B`, `C` (same name, same order, same data type). I want to merge or append these two streams into a single stream containing the columns `A`, `B`, `C`. However, when I use merge join (with the option `FUL OUTER JOIN`) my result is a stream with the columns: `A`, `B`, `C`, `A_1`, `B_1`, `C_1`. It is not what I want. I tried to use the append stream step, but in this case appeared nothing in the preview.

Comment: I problably did something else another time. I used append stream step again, and now it worked! The result is exactly what I need.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As per your requirement first create two stream.

Here we have taken two streams i.e. "stream1.xls" and "stream2.xls".

Then built the transformation using the "Sorted merge" join

For better understanding please refer the screenshots.

[image]

[image]